# How to mock a specific overload of a function with Jest in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am using Jest to mock the `fs.promises.readDir` function.
At first I created a mock with ts-jest and then tried to set up the mock as follows:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
jest.mock('fs');

const mockFs = mocked(fs, true);

describe(..., () => {
  it(..., () => {
    mockFs.promises.readdir.mockResolvedValue(['a.txt']);
  });
});
```

The problem that I am facing with is that TypeScript can not find the proper overload which returns a promise of a `string[]` but the one that returns a promise of a `Dirent[]`.

Moreover it also says that `mockFs.promises` is undefined.

How can I make it work and mock the right function?

Comment: You cannot mock just a specific overload, because the function itself isn't overloaded, only the signature is. There's still just one function implementation backing it.

Comment: `jest.mock` is used to mock a module, if your need is to simulate specific function, you should use `jest.spyOn(fs.promises, 'readdir').mockResolvedValue(...)` instead.

Comment: I am trying to mock this same thing in Jest and found an approach at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813366/249218 that worked well for me. The line now looks like `(jest.spyOn(fsPromises, 'readdir') as unknown as jest.SpyInstance<Promise<string[]>>).mockResolvedValue(expectedFiles);`