# How can I set correctly types on jest.spyOn?

Tags: typescript, mocking, ts-jest

I have written the following on my typescript jest tests:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest
      .spyOn<MyParentClass, any>(MyChildClass.prototype, "doRequest")
      .mockImplementation(async function (this:MyChildClass) {
              /// do my mock
      }  as () => never);
```

The part `as () => never` was added to skip type checker error on the async
saying that

```
Argument of type '(this:MyChildClass) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => unknown'
```

I don't find a way on how to improve the following, narrowing any to a more precise type  : `.spyOn<MyParentClass, any>`

By definition

```
function jest.spyOn<T extends {}, M extends jest.NonFunctionPropertyNames<Required<T>>>(object: T, method: M, accessType: "get"): jest.SpyInstance<Required<T>[M], []> (+3 overloads)
```

I tried other types that might fit but no success...

Tests are running successfully and I'm able to spyOn and mock, just wonder how to write a better typing def.

Comment: Can you show the type of `doRequest` method?

Comment: async doRequest<T>(options: {
    method: string;
    endpoint: string;
}): Promise<T>

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue mocking a fs promise for readdir. I found an approach at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813366/249218 that worked well for me. The spyOn line now looks like `(jest.spyOn(fsPromises, 'readdir') as unknown as jest.SpyInstance<Promise<string[]>>).mockResolvedValue(expectedFiles);` Feels like that'd be applicable here too.